# Tie circle radius to window size in Python Turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, drawing, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

In Python turtle, when drawing objects on the screen, if there was a way to have a circle's radius connected to the window width or height, so that it can be resized by altering the window size?

Comment: Your question is Too Broad. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You will need to create an event that the turtle will listen to: In the following example, if you click on the turtle, a circle of half the width of the canvas will be drawn.
If you resize the canvas, and click on the turtle again, a new circle of half the 
new width will be redrawn.

```
import turtle


def start(dummy_a, dummy_b):
    t.reset()
    y, x = screen.window_height(), screen.window_width()
    t.home()
    t.circle(x/4)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    screen = turtle.Screen()
    t = turtle.Turtle()

    t.onclick(start, add=True)
    screen.listen()
    turtle.done()
```

Comment: Awesome, this was the kind of thing that I was looking for. Thanks a heap.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my alternative *click to adjust drawing to resized window* solution:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def onResize(x=0, y=0):
    screen.onclick(None)  # disable events inside event handler

    screen.setworldcoordinates(-1, -1, 1, 1)

    screen.onclick(onResize)

screen = Screen()
onResize()  # establish initial coordinate system

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)

turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(-0.5)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.circle(0.5, steps=30)

screen.mainloop()
```

Note that we're *not* redrawing anything, we're just readjusting our virtual coordinates (unit square in this example) and letting turtle redraw things.  If we're willing to peek under the hood, we can take this one step further:

```
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import RawTurtle, TurtleScreen, ScrolledCanvas

class MyTurtleScreen(TurtleScreen):

    def __init__(self, cv):
        super().__init__(cv)

        cv.bind('<Configure>', self.onResize)

    def onResize(self, event=None):
        self.setworldcoordinates(-1, -1, 1, 1)

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = ScrolledCanvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)

screen = MyTurtleScreen(canvas)
screen.onResize()  # establish initial coordinate system

turtle = RawTurtle(screen, visible=False)

turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(-0.5)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.circle(0.5, steps=30)

screen.mainloop()
```

This is a generic *embedding turtle in tkinter* example except that I've customized `TurtleScreen` to accept a `Configure` event.  Now, when you resize the window, the coordinate system trick from before kicks in *automatically* so you don't need to click on the window -- it just happens.